# Changing size of a loading gif

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the code below as loading gif for my webpage but was wondering how I could make the size of the gif smaller? Every time I try to change the size it changes the size of the entire thing and not the gif itself.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
            $('.loader').fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        },1000);
})
```

```css
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://bosonprotein.com/onewebmedia/Magiska%20Bollar.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `background-size` propety so:

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://bosonprotein.com/onewebmedia/Magiska%20Bollar.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(0,0,0);
    background-size:10%;
}
```

Working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/0s9vjaL0/).

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

P.S. You can also use px,em,..

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {});
}, 1000);
```

```css
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://bosonprotein.com/onewebmedia/Magiska%20Bollar.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(0,0,0);
    background-size:10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loader"></div>
```